# will elasticsearch date_histogram check the date inside the interval exist or not? And if so , what will happen? If no any error handling for this

Tags: elasticsearch

So far i am working on the ES date histogram for getting monthly result, and my query is like

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sales_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
                "calendar_interval": "1M",
                "offset":    Cutoff          

      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the return is like

```
                  date
1             10978.521    2020-11-20    5995.69  
2             11177.911    2020-12-20     199.39  
3             11177.911    2021-01-20       0.00
```

So my question is :
what if the date "20" is not exist ? and any error handling from ES?
thanks

Jeff

Comment: What do you mean by "the date does not exist"?

Comment: @Val For example  "2020-12-20" dont have doc at that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a monthly date histogram, each bucket must have a date key. That date key is the date of the beginning of the monthly bucket. For instance, `2020-11-20` is the key and the starting date of the bucket starting on that date. In that bucket, you will find all documents whose date is between `2020-11-20` and `2020-12-20`.

Same thing for the last bucket which starts on `2021-01-20`, it will contain all documents starting on that date and going through `2021-02-20`. It doesn't matter whether you have documents whose date field is specifically on those bucket key dates, those keys are just interval bounds.

Comment: ok thanks ~ and i guess you answer my question as i overlook the DOC count within it,
so it seems that what i want to encounter is some date missing in date range aggregation and seems answer is listed in this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

Comment: sorry one more question what if the date key is 2020-02-30 ?

Comment: It means you have at least one document between the 2020-02-30 and 2020-03-31